# Mahout and Spark version compatibility

Tags: apache-spark, version, mahout

I am currently using Mahout 0.13.0. When I try to use spark-itemsimilarity I get an error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf

I suspect it may be an issue with Spark version, but I can't find what version of Spark do I need. I am currently using Spark 2.1.0.

So my question is, with which version of Spark is Mahout 0.13.0 compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no binaries for Mahout 0.13.0 on Spark 2.1 / Scala 2.11, however it is possible to build Mahout for Spark 2.1 (unfortunately there are no profiles, have to do it all with D switches)

to build you need to do the following:

`git clone http://github.com/apache/mahout`

`cd mahout`

`mvn clean package -Dspark.version=2.1.0 -Dscala.version=2.11.8 -Dscala.compat.version=2.11`

Also, Pat is correct- release coming hopefully very very soon, will have binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a maven profile in the develop branch for building with Spark 2.x and Scala 2.11 but no artifacts published until 0.13.1 coming in a week or so.

It is compatible with both, just too many combinations of artifacts to catch up with.